# Conditional for to get keys and single values from dictionary of lists

Tags: python

I have some code to get the key from a dictionary, along with all the values from a list containing `gallery`. The list is assigned to the key.

My code:

```
photos_dict = {}
for key, list in sets_dict.items():
    for item in (item for item in list if 'gallery' in item):
        photos_dict[key] = item
print(photos_dict)
```

And my dictionary(`sets_dict`):

```
{  
   'A':[  
      'http://example.com/gallery
      'http://example.com/video
   ],
   'B':[  
      'http://example.com/gallery
   ],
   'C':[  
      'http://example.com/gallery
   ],
   'A':[  
      'http://example.com/gallery
      'http://example.com/video
   ],
   'D':[  
      'http://example.com/video
      'http://example.com/gallery
   ],
   'E':[  
      'http://example.com/gallery
      'http://example.com/video
   ],
   'F':[  
      'http://example.com/gallery
   ],
   'G':[  
      'http://example.com/gallery
   ],
   'H':[  
      'http://example.com/gallery
      'http://example.com/video
   ],
   'I':[  
      'http://example.com/gallery
   ],
   'J':[  
      'http://example.com/gallery
   ],
   'K':[  
      'http://example.com/gallery
      'http://example.com/video
   ],
   'L':[  
      'http://example.com/gallery
   ],
   'M':[  
      'http://example.com/gallery
      'http://example.com/video
   ],
   'N':[  
      'http://example.com/gallery
   ]
}
```

Is there any way to write this shorter? I would like to have the `if 'gallery in item'` as a conditional in the first for statement.

Comment: what is the required format for `photos_dict`. mention that as well with the question

Comment: Do you have closing quotes and commas in your value lists of dictionary?

Comment: @Lafexlos Sorry, yes there are closing quotes, for some reason they aren't in the above example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write it using *dict comprehension* as:

```
{key: link for key, links in photos_dict.items() for link in links if 'gallery' in link}
```

Save this in `photos_dict`